# Remove line break from mulitline text in SharePoint xslt

Tags: xslt

I am working with SharePoint library and DataView webpart. I have a SharePoint list in which one of the column is a multi-line text. I have inserted a DataView webpart in the designer using the list. In code behind I am acessing the Columns of the list and generating the xml string out of it. But when I access the column with multi-line text the xslt causes line breaks in xaml string which I dont want. Can any one tell me how can I get rid of the  line breaks? Below is the xslt. **Description ** is the column with multi-line

```
....
....
<xsl:for-each select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row">

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[+ ' <BOOK Description ="]]></xsl:text>

<xsl:value-of select="./@Description " />
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[" PRICE="]]></xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="@price" />

<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA["/>']]></xsl:text>

</xsl:for-each>
....
....
```

Xml generated:

```
+ ' <BOOK Description ="sdfdfdfdgfgfg
fgfgfgfgfgfg
sharmila" PRICE="45"/>'
+ ' </BOOK>'
```

The above xml generated has unwanted line-breaks I need the xml to be generated as below.

```
+ ' <BOOK Description ="sdfdfdfdgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgfgsharmila" PRICE="45"/>'
+ ' </BOOK>'
```

Thanks and Regards,
Sharmila

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to replace your `<xsl:value-of select="./@Description " />` with the following code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(./@Description,'&#xA;','')"/>
```

This should remove all line breaks from the Description column.

Comment: Thanks:) but it is not working for me. I have tried using <xsl:value-of select="translate(./@Description,'&lt;br&gt;','\\n')"/>

Comment: but why are you replacing to `'\\n'`? replace to empty string `''`.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the below post .I hope this would help you
http://www.thesug.org/Blogs/kyles/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=28&RootFolder=%2FBlogs%2Fkyles%2FLists%2FPosts

Comment: Thanks :) But where can I find the itemstyle.xsl ?? I am using WSS 3.0